# Programmatically changing UV/Image Editor Image

Tags: python, scripting, uv-image-editor

For a school project, i am trying to combine openCV and Blender and for this very spesific reason, i would like to use Blender's internal Image Editor to show my frames instead of **cv2.imshow()** function.

I'm trying to write a function to refresh Image Editor's image, but i'm not sure how to do that efficiently, without breaking Blender.

```
def preview(frame): # frame is the np.array from my webcam
    img = bpy.data.images['preview']
    img.pixels = frame             # this didn't work
    img.pixels = np.ravel(frame)   # this didn't work either
    img.pixels = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame.astype('uint8'))  # no luck with this one too
```

Is there any good, efficient way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: try this `bpy.data.images.load(frame)`

Comment: @tomasantunes sorry for the reply for this ancient post, i couldn't work on this project for a while. I tried your solution and sadly no luck with it either.

Comment: bpy.data.images.load() function is looking for a path to load the file, and i don't think writing a file and reading it realtime will be efficient.